# I am missing something important with Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

It seems that almost every Boolean expression I try and solve, I always find a [Boolean Discrepancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAKdT.jpg) . I could go back and use a different property, theorem, or law at different points of the process, and get a different solution every time. Obviously this means I am missing some information.

Depending on the decisions made in the moment, it will drastically change the equation, and will result in a different binary output from the answer.
I am aware that sometimes with 'Karnaugh Maps' you can get rid of certain values in the Boolean logic. And you can get a further simplified expression.

What rules or information am I missing that determines what rules I should use at certain points of the simplification of an expression?

There are laws to follow, but what is illegal to do in Boolean Algebra?

Supply me with any additional information you have about this topic.

Comment: I didn't look any further, but right at the beginning, when you invoke rule #8, and say $$AB+\bar{A}\bar{B}=1,$$ that's wrong, since $\bar{A}\bar{B}\neq\overline{AB}$. Indeed, by de Morgan's laws, $$\bar{A}\bar{B}=\overline{A+B}.$$

Comment: What I was taught is that 'Something' + 1 = 1, or 'Specific Something' + 0 = 'Specific Something'. You could put anything in this invisible box in place of a variable, and the result would come out the same according to the laws. Because the operation + or • is where the importance lies, as well as the number after the operator.

https://youtu.be/hQefZ6d9m2k?t=1439 

Now I am more confused than ever, because that was the entire basis of how I learned Boolean Algebra. Guess I should check the binary tables more often.

Are there any of these ≠ illegals that I should be aware of?

Comment: Those laws you refer to in your comment are correct, but that's not what you apply right in the second passage in the linked image. It is correct that $A+\bar{A}=1$, but it is **not correct** that $AB+\bar{A}\bar{B}=1$. For example, if $A=0$ and $B=1$, then $$AB+\bar{A}\bar{B}=0\cdot1+1\cdot0=0+0=0.$$

Comment: I assessed that the moment I read your comment. Thank you for the clarification amrsa. I don't know why I let that slip through unaddressed.